# How to resolve Canon Rebel T2i Error 70?

Tags: canon, canon-550d, error

I was shooting video with my Rebel T2i (Canon 50mm 1.4 lens) when I got an error saying:

> #### Err 70
>
> Shooting is not possible due to an error. 
>   Turn the camera off and on again or re-install the battery.

I reset camera settings, took the battery out, formatted the memory card, and still haven't had any luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: First place you should have checked is attached CD that has troubleshooting application...

Comment: Have you tried an additional memory card?

Comment: Solution I found for Canon 7D... http://www.reikan.co.uk/photography/blog/?p=1550

Answer (score 1):

From some google searching I've found this to be a common problem, specially for higher end bodies like 5D Mark II.

If this continues to happen even after you did what the camera instructed you to do, its best you **send it back to Canon** for a check. If its still under warranty, they'll fix it or replace it.

Also, did you upgrade your firmware or add a grip? Some people reported this error after they started using a grip or after they upgraded their firmware.